# How do I return a union as an Active Record object?

Tags: yii2

I have these union in my controller :

```
$expression = new Expression('"News"');

$featuredNews2= news::find()
   ->alias('ne')
   ->select(['ne.title', 'ne.content','ne.featuredOrder',  'category'=>$expression])
   ->innerJoinWith('featuredOrder1');

$expression2 = new Expression('"Event"');

$featuredEvents2 = event::find()
    ->select(['ev.title', 'ev.content','ev.featuredOrder','category'=>$expression2])
    ->from('event ev')
    ->innerJoinWith('featuredOrder2');

$union =  $featuredNews2->union($featuredEvents2);
```

The relation in model :
news model

```
    public function getFeaturedOrder1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Featured::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }
```

event model

```
public function getFeaturedOrder2()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Featured::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }
```

I need to return the query as an Active Query because I need to access my model's method e.g : `$model->featuredOrder1->preview` in my view. 
The following works but it returns an array, as the result I can't access my model's method :

```
 $unionQuery =  (new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')
    ->from($union)
    ->orderBy('featuredOrder')->all(\Yii::$app->db2);
```

I have two questions :

1. How to return the equivalent $unionQuery above but as an active query object? I have googled and search on SO but what I found is how to return it as array.
2. This is out of curiosity, I wonder why I should provide my db connection as argument in my $unionQuery `all()` method above. If I didn't use an argument that point to `db2`, it will look for table name inside my `db` database instead ( db is my parent database, this db2 is my module's database/the correct one). This only happen with a `union`. My news and event model already have this in getdb() function:

```
return Yii::$app->get('db2');
```

**update**
I've tried this too :

```
$unionProvider =  (new ActiveQuery(Featured::className()))->select('*')
    ->from(['union' => $featuredEvents2->union($featuredNews2)])
    ->orderBy('featuredOrder');
```

With this relation in `featured` model:

```
 public function getNews()
    {
return $this->hasOne(News::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }

public function getEvents()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::className(), ['featuredOrder' => 'featuredOrder']);
    }
```

and in the view, I tried this :

```
foreach($unionProvider as $key=>$model){
echo $model->news->title;
}
```

but get this error : `Trying to get property of non-object`

**Update 2**
I forgot to add `->all()` in my `$unionProvider`, but after that I got this error instead : `PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes)`

Might be something wrong with my query? Can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pure SQL. Plus you can test to see if it is returning the correct results and then add it in the statement below.

```php
$customers = Customer::findBySql('SELECT * FROM customer')->all();
```

[Learn more in yii docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#findBySql()-detail)